What is the most efficient way to multiprocess over a very large dataframe?
I have a large Dataframe that I need to do a lot of matching operations over, and in the past have always used the below method for doing it. However, the Dataframe that I am currently attempting to multiprocess is a 2 GB CSV file that my computer is having problems multiprocessing over, even with only one partition. I am assuming it is because when the Dataframe is split into chunks for multiprocessing, it is than doubling the amount of memory needed, and therefore my computer cannot handle it. This is my current code:
def parallelize_dataframe(df, func, additional_param, num_partitions):
    df_split = np.array_split(df, num_partitions)
    results = []
    with ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=num_partitions) as executor:
        futures = {executor.submit(func, chunk, additional_param): chunk for chunk in df_split}
        for future in tqdm(futures, total=len(futures), desc="Overall progress"):
            results.append(future.result())
    return pd.concat(results)

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Have you considered Polars in the place of Pandas.

If your task is CPU-bound, multiprocessing in Python will make it SLOWER, since the GIL is still in place. Use polars or post the details of your matching here for better answer

@CodeDifferent multiprocessing (vs multithreading) is specifically how to get around the GIL in python (perhaps starting to change as of 3.13 with no-GIL builds). If you can create a workflow that does not transfer too much data between processes and is CPU bound; multiprocessing will absolutely be able to give a speedup.

for tasks such as this I would suggest pre-processing the csv file to separate it into approximately equal chunks which are read in by the child process rather than being read by the main process and sent to the child process. The sending of that data from main to child takes quite a bit of overhead (and memory). Here's an example:
from multiprocessing import Pool
from io import BytesIO
import pandas as pd

csvfile = r"c:\some\example\data.csv"

chunksize = 2**20  # 1MiB chunk size (try different values depending on file size and processing speed)

#example csv contents
# colA,colB,colC
# 1,2,3
# 4,5,6
# 7,8,9
# ...

def sum_cols(args):
    file_start, file_end, col_names = args  # unpack tuple args as Pool.imap_unordered only supports a single arg
    with open(csvfile, "rb") as f:
        f.seek(file_start)
        buf = BytesIO(f.read(file_end-file_start))  # store chunk of csv in a buffer to pass to pandas
    df = pd.read_csv(buf, names=col_names)  # col_names aren't in the chunk so pass them explicitly
    return df.sum()
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    with open(csvfile, "rb") as f:
        firstline = f.readline()
        headers = [col_title.strip() for col_title in firstline.split(b",")]
        startpoints = []
        endpoints = []
        while True:  # scan the file without reading in much data to find good chunk boundaries (start and end on newline)
            startpoints.append(f.tell())
            f.seek(chunksize,1)  # skip ahead by chunksize bytes
            line = f.readline()  # find the end of the current line
            endpoints.append(f.tell())
            if not line:  # empty line indicates end of the file
                if startpoints[-1] == endpoints[-1]: #if the last chunk landed exactly on the last line of the file, there could be an empty chunk
                    startpoints.pop()
                    endpoints.pop()
                break
    
    arglist = [(start, end, headers) for start, end in zip(startpoints, endpoints)]
    with Pool() as pool:
        print(sum(pool.imap(sum_cols, arglist)))

I have not used polars and can't make an answer based on that, but my understanding is that it is very fast.

It seems to me that when you execute f.seek(chunksize,1) if you happen to seek to within the last line of the file, then when you do the next iteration of while True; you will be creating a new entry in arglist that will result in sum_cols creating a dataframe with no rows.

I believe Aaron's answer to be a reasonable approach. But let me offer a few suggestions:
In creating arglist, it is possible for the execution of f.seek(chunksize,1) to position the next read within the final row of the CSV file. Consequently, on the next iteration we are actually at end of file but a new entry will be added to arglist that will result in an empty dataframe to be created in sum_cols.
In general, you want to be partitioning a large CSV file into some number of dataframes such that if the original cell contents were strings, then the dataframes' cell contents will be strings.
A suitable chunksize argument should be passed to imap as a function of the number tasks that will be enqueued to the pool and the pool size. This will boost performance when there is a large number of tasks being submitted to the multiprocessing pool.
There are additionally several things we night do to reduce memory usage. Since multiprocessing.pool.imap is being used, there is no reason why arglist should not be either a generator expression or replaced with a generator function allowing you to save some memory. Additional memory can be saved by not having to explicitly pass the constant column names for each submitted task.
from multiprocessing import Pool, cpu_count
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd
from functools import partial

csvfile = r"c:\some\example\data.csv"

chunk_bytes = 2**20  # 1MiB chunk byte size (try different values depending on file size and processing speed)
n_tasks = 2000  # approximation of: file size / chunk_bytes

#example csv contents
# colA,colB,colC
# 1,2,3
# 4,5,6
# 7,8,9
# ...

def sum_cols(col_names, args):
    file_start, file_end = args  # Unpack args
    with open(csvfile, "rb") as f:
        f.seek(file_start)
        buf = StringIO(f.read(file_end-file_start).decode("utf-8"))  # store chunk of csv in a buffer to pass to pandas
    df = pd.read_csv(buf, names=col_names)  # col_names aren't in the chunk so pass them explicitly
    return df.sum()

if __name__ == "__main__":

    def compute_chunksize(iterable_size, pool_size):
        chunksize, remainder = divmod(iterable_size, 4 * pool_size)
        if remainder:
            chunksize += 1
        return chunksize

    def generate_args(file_size, f):
        file_start = f.tell()
        while file_start < file_size:  # scan the file without reading in much data to find good chunk boundaries (start and end on newline)
            f.seek(chunk_bytes, 1)  # skip ahead by chunksize bytes
            line = f.readline()  # find the end of the current line
            file_end = f.tell()
            yield file_start, file_end
            file_start = file_end

    pool_size = cpu_count()
    chunksize = compute_chunksize(n_tasks, pool_size)

    with open(csvfile, "rb") as f:
        file_size = f.seek(0, 2)
        f.seek(0, 0) # Seek back to the beginning:
        firstline = f.readline()
        headers = [col_title for col_title in firstline.decode("utf-8").strip().split(",")]

        with Pool(pool_size) as pool:
            worker = partial(sum_cols, headers)
            print(sum(pool.imap(worker, generate_args(file_size, f), chunksize=chunksize)))

